# How to logout from one tab and affect the rest of the tabs?

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

I have a question, assuming I have a controller with:

> -Login -Index -Ventana random -LogOff

And the Ventana random opens in a new tab so we would have two tabs (Index and Ventana random), How can I make it from the Ventana random tab, when pressing the logout button, the Index tab returns to the Login screen ?

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult Login(string uname, string psw)
    {
        Session["uname"] = uname;
        Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
        if(uname == null || psw == null)
        {
            return View("Login");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                ConexionSQL sql = new ConexionSQL();
                var usuario = sql.login(uname, psw);
                var existencia = sql.usuarioOCobrador(uname, psw);

                if (existencia[0].usuario == "USUARIO")
                {
                    var caracteres = Convert.ToString(psw);
                    var pruebaUsuario = sql.datos(uname);

                    if (pruebaUsuario[0].clave == caracteres)
                    {
                        if (pruebaUsuario[0].nivel == 8 //nada
                            || pruebaUsuario[0].nivel == 9
                            || pruebaUsuario[0].nivel == 11
                            || pruebaUsuario[0].nivel == 12
                            || pruebaUsuario[0].nivel == 13
                            || pruebaUsuario[0].nivel == 15)
                        {
                            ViewBag.Usu = "Usted no cuenta o no tiene los permisos suficientes para ingresar al sistema. Comuníquese con su Departamento.";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return View("Index", usuario);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.Contra = "Contraseña incorrecta.";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Usu = "Usuario incorrecto o usted no tiene los permisos para ingresar al sistema. Comuníquese con su Departamento.";
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        return View("Login");
    }

    [NoCache]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Session.Clear();
        Session.RemoveAll();
        Session.Abandon();
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
    }

public class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");

        var cache = GetCache(filterContext);

        cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        cache.SetNoStore();

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    protected virtual HttpCachePolicyBase GetCache(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        return filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
    }
}
```

In the Index view I have this button:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-danger my-2 my-sm-0" onclick="window.open('VentanaRandom.html')" type="button">Open new tab</button>
```

This opens a new tab for me with this button:

```
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 ml-auto" method="post" action="@Url.Action("LogOff", "Home")">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Cerrar sesión</button>
    </form>
```

Now that I have the two tabs open, how do I make the first tab with Index go to the Login screen from the second one after pressing the logout button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a controller action like `IsStillLoggedIn` that checks if you still have a valid cookie (or whichever authentication scheme you use), perhaps you could use the [`visibilitychange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) event on the document in JavaScript - something like this:

```js
function ensureStillLoggedIn() {
  if (document.visibilityState === "visible") {
    // Tab is now active, check if we're still logged in
    fetch("/Home/IsStillLoggedIn", { credentials: "same-origin" })
        .then(response => {
            if (response === "false") {
                window.location = "/Home/Login";
            }
        });
  }
}

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", ensureStillLoggedIn);
```

Then run this JavaScript whenever the page loads. This way, the user should be logged out when they switch to that tab.

Comment: Thank you for your helpo and time !!